# Octave Treats a 5000*10 Matrix As a 16*4 Matrix

Tags: matlab, octave, octave-gui

I'm trying to use Octave to submit an assignment written in MATLAB.`h_theta2` matrix is a 5000*10 matrix in MATLAB (please see the attached screenshot) and the code works fine in MATLAB. But when I try to submit the assignment in Octave it returns the following error:

Submission failed: operator -: nonconformant arguments (op1 is 16x4, op2 is 5000x10)

LineNumber: 98 (Which refers to `delta3=h_theta2-y_2` in the attached screenshot.)

[image]

This (I'm guessing) means that Octave is treating `h_theta2` as a 16*4 matrix.

The code is supposed to estimate the cost function and gradient of a neural network. X, y, Theta1 and Theta2 are given in the assignment.

```
function [J grad] = nnCostFunction(nn_params, ...
                               input_layer_size, ...
                               hidden_layer_size, ...
                               num_labels, ...
                               X, y, lambda)
```

NNCOSTFUNCTION Implements the neural network cost function for a two-layer neural network which performs classification.
`[J grad] = NNCOSTFUNCTON(nn_params, hidden_layer_size, num_labels, ..., X, y, lambda)` computes the cost and gradient of the neural network. The parameters for the neural network are "unrolled" into the vector nn_params and need to be converted back into the weight matrices.

The returned parameter grad should be an "unrolled" vector of the partial derivatives of the neural network.

Reshape `nn_params` back into the parameters `Theta1` and `Theta2`, the weight matrices. For 2-layer neural network:

```
Theta1 = reshape(nn_params(1:hidden_layer_size * (input_layer_size + 1)), ...
             hidden_layer_size, (input_layer_size + 1));

Theta2 = reshape(nn_params((1 + (hidden_layer_size * (input_layer_size + 1))):end), ...
             num_labels, (hidden_layer_size + 1));

m = size(X, 1);
```

I need to return the following variables correctly:

```
J = 0;
Theta1_grad = zeros(size(Theta1));
Theta2_grad = zeros(size(Theta2));
```

Sigmoid function is defined in another file and is recalled here to calculate `h_theta1` and `h_theta2`.

```
%Sigmoid function:
function g = sigmoid(z)
%SIGMOID Compute sigmoid function
%   J = SIGMOID(z) computes the sigmoid of z.
g = 1.0 ./ (1.0 + exp(-z));
end
```

Feedforward the neural network and return the cost in the variable J:

```
X = [ones(m, 1) X];
h_theta1=sigmoid(X*Theta1');

h_theta1=[ones(m,1) h_theta1];
h_theta2=sigmoid(h_theta1*Theta2');


y_2=zeros(5000,10);

for k=1:10
    condition=y(:,1)==k;
        y_2(condition,k)=1;
end


for i=1:m
   for k=1:num_labels
      e(i,k)=-y_2(i,k)'*log(h_theta2(i,k))-(1-y_2(i,k)')*log(1-h_theta2(i,k));
   end
end


J=(1/m)*sum(e);
J=sum(J);
Theta_1=Theta1;
Theta_2=Theta2;
Theta_1(:,1)=[];
Theta_2(:,1)=[];

%Regularized cost function:

J=J+(lambda/(2*m))*(sum(sum(Theta_1.*Theta_1))+sum(sum(Theta_2.*Theta_2)));

%Gradient calculation

delta3=h_theta2-y_2;
delta2=(delta3*Theta2).*h_theta1.*(1-h_theta1);
Theta2_grad=Theta2_grad+delta3'*h_theta1;
Theta2_grad=(1/m)*Theta2_grad;
delta_2=delta2;
delta_2(:,1)=[];
Theta1_grad=Theta1_grad+delta_2'*X;
Theta1_grad=(1/m)*Theta1_grad;
```

I then submit the above code using a `submit()` function in Octave. The code works for `J` calculation but then gives the following error:

```
octave:80> submit()
== Submitting solutions | Neural Networks Learning...
Use token from last successful submission? (Y/n): Y

!! Submission failed: operator -: nonconformant arguments 
(op1 is 16x4, op2 is 5000x10)


Function: nnCostFunction
LineNumber: 98

Please correct your code and resubmit.
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Can you add the code in plain text so that we can test it, as well as a screen shot from Octave showing the error and the content of the workspace? What do you get if you type `which h_theta_2` in Octave?

Comment: Please read [mre] and also [reasons to not upload images of code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/7328782).

Comment: Where is the code? Please post the whole script as text for people to test.

Comment: Thanks, @StewieGriffin. I added my codes. When I type `which h_theta2` I get nothing!

Comment: Do you have more than one `sigmoid` function? Type `which -all sigmoid`.

Comment: Thanks, @CrisLuengo. I just have one sigmoid function. `>>> octave:84> which -all sigmoid
                                ^

octave:85> 'sigmoid' is a function from the file /Machine Learning/Week 5/BrXPo7etR16`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out where the problem was. The thing is the grader tests my answer with a totally different dataset and I had created `y_2` with fixed dimensions. What I should've done instead was to create `y_2` as follows:

```
y_2=zeros(m,num_labels);


for k=1:num_labels
    condition=y(:,1)==k;
        y_2(condition,k)=1;
end
```

Which makes the code work for any value of m and num_labels.

Comment: I can't test it, since I don't have all the data, but I believe your code can be changed to: `y_2 = bsxfun(@eq, y, (1:num_labels)')`

Comment: Actually just `y == (1:num_labels)'` since MATLAB now has implicit expansion.